# which is the best way to encrypt internet?

Tags: encryption, tls, vpn

i want to know which is totally end to end encrypted methods for internet surf ..? like vpn .. i heard that nsa cracked vpn .. is there any other method for private internet surfing?

Comment: There are like a billion ways to encrypt data on the wire. What exactly are your needs?

Comment: i need to encrypt my internet   connection like vpn .. any other way end to end ecryption ?

Comment: `end to end encryption` usually means from the client to the server. A VPN only encrypts between the client and the VPN server, not the final destination server. Are you only sending messages to the VPN server?

Comment: yes am only  but  nsa already crack vpn they are monitoring  any other encryption methods to surf internet privately?

Comment: Can you specify exactly what your requirements? Asking for NSA-proof encryption without specifying what that means makes answering this question difficult.

Comment: hello why do you hold my question ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad idea to run OpenVPN server on a VPS. Why would it be? The only problem I see is if your server is not secure. Otherwise you can also use I2P for instance. If you don't like to run OpenVPN you could also create an SSH tunnel between your host and your server

Comment: l2tp is not safe nsa already cracked

Comment: They also cracked SSL with Diffie Huffman and they hacked my ISP... So what do you suggest?